# Can I buy mutual funds on an Interactive Broker ISA account?

Tags: mutual-funds, interactive-brokers

I live in UK and I don't see in the interactive brokers settings a way to enable trading permissions for mutual funds in my ISA account. I wonder if this is not allowed only in Interactive Brokers or any other broker's ISA accounts in UK? or is there a way I can enable mutual funds for Interactive Brokers as well.
Note that for the margin account I can buy mutual funds without any issues, but only in the ISA account I can't